# Boot Strape add hidden Button to form,how to prevent it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have form to validate using bootstrape validator,but when i submit the form its redirect to current url instead of specified action url, thats only because of hidden button added by the bootstrape validator to form. any suggestion for how to stop this?

following is my form

```
<div class="form_videos">
 <form id="webLinkForm" method="POST" name="webLinkForm" action="{{url('/')}}/adminarea/videos/savelink" data-toggle="validator" role="form" >
            <input type="hidden" id="itemID" name="itemID" value="{{$itemID}}">
                <input type="hidden" id="videoTypeID" name="videoTypeID" value="{{$videoTypeID}}">
                <input type="hidden" id="videoID" name="videoID" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="method" name="method" value="add">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Video Link</label>
                        <a href="#"><img src="{{ url('/') }}/components/images/help_icon.png" alt="Help" title="" /></a>
                        <input type="text" name="weblink" id="weblink" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Video Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="caption" id="caption" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Video Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control textarea" id="description" name="description" maxlength="150"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save Link" form="webLinkForm">
                </div>
        </form>
        <br/>
</div>
```

following is my js code on document.ready
   $('#webLinkForm').bootstrapValidator({
         framework: 'bootstrap',
         icon: {
             valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
             invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
             validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
         },
        fields: {
                    weblink: 
                    {
                        message: 'Please Enter Video Link.',
                        validators: 
                            {
                                notEmpty:{message: 'Please Enter Video Link'},
                            }
                    },
                    caption:{
                        message: 'Please Enter Caption.',
                        validators: 
                            {
                                notEmpty:{message: 'Please Enter Caption.'},
                            }
                        }
        }
    });

Comment: mark hidden button as button not submit. `<input type='button' ... />`

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ?

Comment: but its dynamically added by bootstrap how can i prevent it?

Comment: Hope you should move the submit button from the form. And insert outside the form.

Comment: then how form will be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form_videos">
 <form id="webLinkForm" method="POST" name="webLinkForm" action="{{url('/')}}/adminarea/videos/savelink" data-toggle="validator" role="form" >
            <input hidden="hidden" id="itemID" name="itemID" value="{{$itemID}}">
                <input hidden="hidden" id="videoTypeID" name="videoTypeID" value="{{$videoTypeID}}">
                <input hidden="hidden" id="videoID" name="videoID" value="">
                <input hidden="hidden" id="method" name="method" value="add">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Video Link</label>
                        <a href="#"><img src="{{ url('/') }}/components/images/help_icon.png" alt="Help" title="" /></a>
                        <input type="text" name="weblink" id="weblink" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Video Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="caption" id="caption" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Video Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control textarea" id="description" name="description" maxlength="150"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save Link" form="webLinkForm">
                </div>
        </form>
        <br/>
</div>
```